# Questions about residencies as a photographer

Tags: careers

I just got done with a photography course and have been recommended residencies by various people who have seen my work. Especially ones that focus on science (such as but not limited to https://www.1plus2.fr/en/)

I have been reading blogs online but haven't been able to find photographers who have had firsthand experiences. Some of the questions that I am trying to figure out:

- How does one apply to residencies?
- How does one get selected into residencies?
- What will I achieve from being in a residency?
- Is the purpose to create a new project? Or transform an old one? Do I work with other artists?
- When during someone's career should they go to a residency? Am I too young to apply?
- Do I need to bear the costs?

Is there a specific source I can go to find answers to these questions?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I do not see relation to photography per se. And one of the rules of this site is: **one** question+answers.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Please remember the description of the Photography SE community before some Einstein decided to eliminate all of the FAQs from all of the SE communities. "This site is about the art, science, hobby, and business of photography." This question is squarely on topic within the *business* of photography.

Comment: @Kar This type of thing would tend to be location specific. What part of the world are you in? Here in the U.S., most formal photographic residencies are set up by a graduate level school for their candidates who have otherwise completed all of the course requirements. Most of my knowledge comes from friends/colleagues in photojournalism. Journalism schools set up residencies with journalism outlets. What specific type of photography course/degree have you completed?

Answer (score 2):

"Residency" can be an awful broad term. Some are more like internships for students, others are full fledged positions for veterans in their fields.

Based on my limited experience talking to friends and colleagues who have done residencies that involve photography here in the United States, I'd say the answers to each of your multiple questions will vary greatly from one residency to the next.

One friend who has a Master's Degree in photojournalism from a fairly prestigious graduate school of journalism did several short residencies at newspapers in different areas of the United States that were all set up by the school as part of their requirements for graduation. The school has working relationships with various news agencies located throughout the United States. Maybe even a few international agencies with locations available abroad? The students in the program would list their past experiences, qualifications, and preferences as to which organizations and locations to which they would like to go. Many students, including my friend, already had a few years of PJ experience under their belts before entering the Masters program. Others went straight from earning their Bachelor's degree into grad school. The administrators of the program would then select which students went to which residency partner based on what they felt were the best matches. Students were responsible for their own living expenses, just as when they attended classes on campus (this was before online higher education really took off), but were paid a small stipend by the hosting news agencies as well as compensated for expenses incurred as a direct result of performing their duties. This would include things such as mileage and meal reimbursements for expenses incurred travelling to/from the location of a news assignment.

Another friend who did a one-year stint as "photographer in residence" at a major National Park was already a seasoned veteran landscape photographer. He, along with a few other established landscape photographers, most of whom were invited by the Park's administration, applied directly to the administration of the National Park and was selected from among the candidates. This residency included - but was not limited to - responsibilities as a *teacher*, rather than as a student and paid what would be considered a full salary for an established professional in his field.

The best place to find the answers you are seeking is to contact the administrators of each residency in which you are interested and ask them directly.